# How is the paramter for bayes estimator derived

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, proof

I am reading about bayes estimator and it is given that

[How to derive bayes estimator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Njdj.png)

And the answer is:

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHhh.png)

However, I know that the integration of an exponent will still have an exponent. How is it derived?

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivative of the integral to see whether it equals the integrand? Also, your premise is not correct. For example, the integral of 1/(1+x^2) is arctan(x) +c

Comment: Can you provide the content of your question as text instead of links to it?